# How do I initialize the vector I have defined in my header file?

Tags: c++, vector, header, initialization

I have the following in my Puzzle.h

```
class Puzzle
{
    private:
        vector<int> puzzle;
    public:
        Puzzle() : puzzle (16) {}
        bool isSolved();
        void shuffle(vector<int>& );
};
```

and then my Puzzle.cpp looks like:

```
Puzzle::Puzzle()
{
    // Initialize the puzzle (0,1,2,3,...,14,15)
    for(int i = 0; i <= puzzle.size(); i++)
    {
        puzzle[i] = i;
    }
}

// ... other methods
```

Am I using the initializer list wrong in my header file?  I would like to define a vector of ints and initialize its size to that of 16.  How should I do this?

G++ Output:

```
Puzzle.cpp:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
Puzzle.cpp: In constructor `Puzzle::Puzzle()':
Puzzle.cpp:16: error: expected `)' at end of input
Puzzle.cpp:16: error: expected `{' at end of input
Puzzle.cpp: At global scope:
Puzzle.cpp:24: error: redefinition of `Puzzle::Puzzle()'
Puzzle.cpp:16: error: `Puzzle::Puzzle()' previously defined here
```

Comment: Careful. As Neil points out, your array only has `puzzle.size()` elements, accessed 0 through puzzle.size() - 1. Your loop goes one to many times, make it `i < puzzle.size()`. (Better yet, take heed of Neil's suggestion just to `push_back`. Maybe put `puzzle.reserve(16)` first.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined `Puzzle::Puzzle()` in both the header and the .cpp file, so it has two definitions.

The initializer list can go along with the constructor definition in the .cpp file:

```
Puzzle::Puzzle()
    : puzzle (16)
{
    // ...
}
```

and remove the definition from the header:

```
Puzzle(); // I'm just a declaration now, not a definition
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is you define your constructor twice - once in the header, then again in the cpp file. Remove the one in the header and move the initialization to the cpp:

```
Puzzle::Puzzle()
: puzzle (16)
{
    // Initialize the puzzle (0,1,2,3,...,14,15)
    for(int i = 0; i <= puzzle.size(); i++)
    {
        puzzle[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Moreover, unless you are `using std::vector` - or worse,  `using namespace std` - in your header (which you shouldn't), your vector should be declared like this in the header:

```
    std::vector<int> puzzle;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialise something in two different places. In the header, just declare it:

```
Puzzle();
```

in the .cpp file define it:

```
Puzzle::Puzzle() : puzzle( 16 )
{
    // Initialize the puzzle (0,1,2,3,...,14,15)
    for(int i = 0; i < puzzle.size(); i++)
    {
        puzzle[i] = i;
    }
}
```

though you would probably be better off not using an initialisation list:

```
Puzzle::Puzzle() 
{
    // Initialize the puzzle (0,1,2,3,...,14,15)
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        puzzle.push_back( i );
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `reserve` first, though such a small case probably makes no real difference.

Comment: Just noticed that both my and the OPs code has  a severe off-by-one bug! Now corrected.

Comment: @GMan actually, given the OP's program logic, reserve wouldn't work.

Comment: @GMan Because reserve doesn't change size, which is what the OP is looping on.

Comment: @Neil: Right...you'd `reserve` then `push_back` like you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can not define the constructor twice! So in the header file replace

```
Puzzle() : puzzle (16) {}
```

by

```
Puzzle();
```

And in the .cpp source file add

```
puzzle.resize(16);
```

in the first line.